# Assigning a value to an objects attribute, through multiple functions

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, uitableview

I have an UITableView where user can enter an objects title, date and other values.

The variables that I want the user to define (which are properties) reside inside a NSDictionary.

In the VCs `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I set up a custom cell with the function of

`[cell setUpCellWithVariable:[variableToShowInTable objectForKey:nameOfVariable]];`

Within this function, I determine inputView and other things depending on what sort of variable I pass along. When I close the VC (by custom button), I want to save whichever variable each cell have to the variable passed along to it.

This is the part I can't figure out. Since I am passing along a pointer, the rValue of the pointer will change when I redefine it to equal the input value in the cell. Thus the object property pointer points to its original value.

I hoped the original address of the passed along variable would be saved, and accesible with &, but within the cell object only the rValue of the pointer parameter is preserved. Additionally, since the variable I want user to define is a property (and not an instance variable), I'm having trouble getting the address of it and passing that along in the method.

How can I attack this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide some code from your custom cell class.

Have you tried storing the input variables through MVC pattern? if yes than there should not be such problems.